# Search in 1 million <string Name, int score> pairs using sub-linear time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, json

I have a JSON object which contains 1 million  pairs.

```
var student = {[
    {
        name: "govi",
        score: "65"
    },
    {
        name: "dharti",
        score: "80"
    },
    {
        name: "Akash",
        score: "75"
    },............. till 1 million
    ]
};
```

Now My Concern as below.

I want to build a server program which accepts a user query such that for each query, it will responds with the top 10 names (ranked by score) that start with s or contains '_s' (so for example, both "revenue" and "yearly_revenue" match the prefix "rev"). it's too easy with normal Jquery and json program but there is a condition.

**Condition**

Query answering should run in **sub-linear time** (in terms of the number of names in the input).

Comment: search by `name` or search by `score`? You need to index the array by what is most likely pattern of search

Comment: How much memory do you want to use?

Comment: @gurvinder372 order by score and search by name

Comment: @MineR memory is not issue just want to use on sub-linear time algorithm to achieve it.

Comment: Down vote for what?

Comment: Create a tree structure, each character is a node, in the node you store the top 10 for that node, in each node you store nodes for each letter which follow the first. Stop adding nodes when you have less than 10 in a node. Do a linear search on those 10. Should be log N time.

Comment: @MineR Can u please give me a brief idea about sub-linear time method or algorithm with json or in c#.

Comment: `I want to build a server program which accepts a user queries such that for each query s` How many different queries / search values will you support? Is there a fixed set of them, or can the user search on **anything**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add the Newtonsoft library  from the nuget rep

2) Add the following references

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

3) use this code

```
 //JObjectString is your string that contains the values
            JArray ValuesArray = JArray.Parse(JObjectString);

            Dictionary<string, int> SearchDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            //here the search term is the query from the user input
            string searchTerm = "govi";

            foreach (var rec in ValuesArray)
            {
                SearchDict.Add(rec["name"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(rec["score"].ToString()));
            }
            //here is the result in javascript array format, return it
            string ResultString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SearchDict.Where(o => o.Key == searchTerm | o.Key.Contains(searchTerm)).
                Select(o => o).OrderByDescending(o => o.Value).Take(10).Select(o => o));
```

Comment: It Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort your Array descending by score. this ensures that the next step creates subsets wich are already sorted, and is faster than sorting (often overlapping) subsets.
2. Create a dictionary by char. Go through each char of each name and add the item to the subset.
3. When searching for a substring (like "rev"), you can check the Arrays for each letter, take the shortest and can iterate through that, instead of the whole data.

an example:

```
//building the map
let map = Object.create(null);
data
    //.slice()  /if you can't rearrange the items in the original Array
    .sort((a,b) => b.score - a.score)
    .forEach(item => {
        for(let char of new Set(item.name)){
            var arr = map[char] ||| (map[char] = []);
            arr.push(item);
        }
    });

function findSubset(str){
    let best;
    for(let char of new Set(str)){
        //there can be no entry for "rev", if there is no subset for "v" for example
        if(!(char in map)) return [];

        let arr = map[char];
        if(!best || arr.length < best.length)
            best = arr;
    }
    return best || [];
}

function contains(str, limit=Infinity){
    let subset = findSubset(str);
    let results = [];
    for(let i=0; i<subset.length && results.length < limit; ++i){
        let item = subset[i];
        if(item.name.includes(str))
            results.push(item);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling StudentIndex.GetTop10(string s) will be O(n) where is n is the length of string s. This will consume a lot of memory, but there are a number of ways to cut this down. (Such as doing a linear search once Node.Top10 has less than 10 values).

I leave you to write the tree building.

```
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Score { get; set; }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public Dictionary<char, Node> Children { get; set; }
        public List<Student> Top10 { get; set; }
    }
    public class StudentIndex
    {
        private Node _root;

        public StudentIndex(IEnumerable<Student> students)
        {
            Node root = new Node();

            foreach(var student in students)
            {
                var parts = student.Name.Split(new[] {'_'});
                foreach(var part in parts)
                {
                    //you'll add each student to the tree using each part of the name    
                }
            }
            //set _root
        }

        public IEnumerable<Student> GetTop10(string s)
        {
            return GetTop10(s.ToLower(), _root);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Student> GetTop10(string s, Node node)
        {
            if (node.Children == null) return node.Top10;
            if (s.Length == 0) return node.Top10;

            var c = s[0];
            Node n;
            if (node.Children.TryGetValue(c, out n))
            {
                return GetTop10(s.Substring(1), n);
            }
            else
            {
                return Enumerable.Empty<Student>();
            }
        }
    }
```